Gstreamer- facing error: Failed to link demux video pad to video queue pad. Exiting
I've been studying about gstreamer and I don't understand where I got it wrong but every pipeline I tried turning code would give me 'Elements could not be linked' and I'm running this code on ubuntu. I dont want to use the direct cmd line using gst-launch cuz later I'll have to change the clock properties so please help with the c program itself.
#include <gst/gst.h>

GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demux, *audio_queue, *audio_decode, *audio_convert, *video_queue, *video_decode, *video_convert, *video_overlay, *audio_sink, *video_sink;
    GstPad *audio_pad, *video_pad, *demux_audio_pad, *demux_video_pad, *demux_pad_template;

static int temp = 0;
static void pad_added_callback(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer data) {
GstPad *sink_pad;
GstElement *queue = (GstElement *) data;
GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;

g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME(src));

// Check the new pad's type 
//
new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

// If it's audio, link it to the audio_queue 
//
if (temp == 1) {

g_print("audio pad added");

sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(audio_queue, "sink");
if (gst_pad_link(new_pad, audio_pad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {

        g_error("Failed to link demux audio pad to audio queue pad. Exiting.");
        return;
    }
    temp++;
} else if (temp == 0) {
// If it's video, link it to the video_queue 

g_print("Entered the vid pad");
sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(video_queue, "sink");
if (gst_pad_link(new_pad, video_pad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
        g_error("Failed to link demux video pad to video queue pad. Exiting.");
        return;
    }
    temp++;
} else {
// It is neither audio nor video so we do nothing 
g_print("ajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
return;
}
}

 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;

    // Initialize GStreamer
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Create the pipeline
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    // Create elements
    source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "source");
    demux = gst_element_factory_make("matroskademux", "demux");
    audio_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio_queue");
    audio_decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "audio_decode");
    audio_convert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audio_convert");
    audio_sink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "audio_sink");
    video_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "video_queue");
    video_decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "video_decode");
    video_convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video_convert");
    video_overlay = gst_element_factory_make("clockoverlay", "video_overlay");
    video_sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "video_sink");

    // Check elements creation
    if (!pipeline || !source || !demux || !audio_queue || !audio_decode || !audio_convert || !audio_sink || !video_queue || !video_decode || !video_convert || !video_overlay || !video_sink)  {
        g_error("Failed to create elements. Exiting.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the location of the file to play
    g_object_set(source, "location", "/home/lg/ml/sintel_video.mkv", NULL);

    // Add elements to the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, demux, audio_queue, audio_decode, audio_convert, audio_sink, video_queue, video_decode, video_convert, video_overlay, video_sink, NULL);

    // Link elements
    gst_element_link(source, demux);
    gst_element_link_many(audio_queue, audio_decode, audio_convert, audio_sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many(video_queue, video_decode, video_convert, video_overlay, video_sink, NULL);


    g_signal_connect(demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_callback), NULL);

    // Start playing
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // Listen for messages on the pipeline's bus
    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    // Free resources
    gst_message_unref(msg);
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 1;
}


This is the code am using to demux audio video and stream a file in local directory location: /home/lg/ml/sintel_video.mkv
While compiling I dont get any errors but ./filepgm gives:
muthu:~/ml$ ./clock1
0:00:00.031117832 17158 0x616a13c34100 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3688:gst_base_src_start_complete: pad not activated yet
Received new pad 'video_0' from 'demux':
Entered the vid pad
(clock1:17158): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 01:52:14.180: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed
** (clock1:17158): ERROR **: 01:52:14.181: Failed to link demux video pad to video queue pad. Exiting.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Matroska demuxer produces already decoded streams (x-raw) so no need to have decodebin after the audio_queue and video_queue. Also instead of using matroska demuxer you may use decodebin. Decodebin should automatically (with typefind) detect type of the input and if filesrc is pushing webm input then decodebin will use matroska demuxer transparently for you.
For now you may want to remove audio_decode and video_decode elements from your pipeline.

Thanks a lot :) this helped! now in the code I have to put in 2 separate clocks for audio and video so that the async is achieved, I am able to do the same using audiodelay and sync=false. But the aim is to manually put in diff clocks for a/v and check for its async. Any guidance with that?

I'm not sure I understand what is the problem about/what you want to achieve, instead of how you want to achieve that. Could you elaborate more about that? Setting sync=false in autoaudiosink and autovideosink will cause that each branch of the pipeline will be processing the buffers with its own speed without syncing to the pipeline clock (ignoring PTS)

Yeap, actually I had to change the clocks for audio and video manually. The aim is to achieve async when i use the different clocks but I dont want to use sync=false cuz if I do that both audio and video clock uses GstPulseSinkClock I want them to be different to achieve async.
